# Mock objection model dependecy in NestJs with Jest

Tags: unit-testing, mocking, nestjs, knex.js, objection.js

I'm trying to make unit test with nestjs and objection. The problem I have is that I can't mock the "User" Model that is injected with the decorator "@InjectModel". I searched a lot to find a solution but I didn't find anything.

users.service.ts

```
 import { HttpException, HttpStatus, Inject, Injectable  } from '@nestjs/common';

import { CreateUserDto } from './create-user.dto'; 
import { User } from 'src/app.models';
import { InjectModel } from 'nestjs-objection';
@Injectable()
export class UsersService {
  constructor(
    @InjectModel(User) private readonly userModel: typeof User,
    ) {}

    
    async create(createUserDto: CreateUserDto) {
      try {
        const users = await this.userModel.query().insert(createUserDto);

        return users 
      } catch (err) {
        console.log(err)
        throw new HttpException(err, HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
      }
    }

}
```

users.service.spec.ts

```
import { Test, TestingModule } from "@nestjs/testing";
import { UsersService } from "../src/users/users.service";
import { CreateUserDto } from "src/users/create-user.dto";
import { User } from "../src/app.models";
import { getObjectionModelToken } from 'nestjs-objection';

describe('userService', () => {
    let userService: UsersService;

    beforeEach(async () => {
        const module: TestingModule = await Test.createTestingModule({
            providers: [
                UsersService,
                {
                    provide: User,
                    useValue: {}
                },

            ],
        }).compile();

        userService = module.get<UsersService>(UsersService);
    });

    it('Should be defined', () => {
        expect(userService).toBeDefined();
    });

    it('Should add pin to a created user', async () => {
        const createUserDTO: CreateUserDto = {
            email: 'mockEmail@mock.com',
            userName: 'user'
        }
        const res = await userService.create(createUserDTO)

        expect(res).toHaveProperty('pin')
    });
```

I tried to use `import { getObjectionModelToken } from 'nestjs-objection';` inside provider like this:

```
providers: [
                UsersService,
                {
                    provide: getObjectionModelToken(User),
                    useValue: {}
                },
            ],
```

I got this error
[image]

It asks for a "connection" but I don't know what to put on it.
I suppose "getObjectionModelToken" is the function to mock the "InjectModel". When I pass an empty string
I got this error:

```
 ● Test suite failed to run

    Cannot find module 'src/app.models' from '../src/users/users.service.ts'

    Require stack:
      C:/nestjs-project/nestjs-knex/src/users/users.service.ts
      users.repository.spec.ts

      1 | import { HttpException, HttpStatus, Inject, Injectable  } from '@nestjs/common';
      2 | import { CreateUserDto } from './create-user.dto'; 
    > 3 | import { User } from 'src/app.models';
        | ^
      4 | import {
      5 |   InjectModel,
      6 |   synchronize,

      at Resolver._throwModNotFoundError (../node_modules/jest-resolve/build/resolver.js:491:11)
      at Object.<anonymous> (../src/users/users.service.ts:3:1)
```

If I change the path it breaks the correct functionality of the app

Comment: What "didn't work" about the `getObjectionModelToken()` approach? We need details, errors, things that help us debug the problem

Answer (score 0):

That looks like an error from `jest` not understanding what `src/*` imports are. Either use relative imports rather than absolute (e.g. use `import { User } from '../app.models'`) or tell jest how to resolve `src/*` imports via the `moduleNameMapper` in your `jest.config.js` or `package.json`

```json
{
  "moduleNameMapper": {
    "^src/(.*)$": "<rootDir>/path/to/src/$1"
  }
}
```

I *think* based on the error your `/path/to/src` should be `../src` but I'm not 100% sure, so make sure you set that correctly.